# Magento 1.9 Additinal info attribute with icon

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, custom-attributes

Currently the additional information shows the names of the attributes and then the content, like the image for example:

[image]

I would like to have icons for some attributes to show, the icons should take the place of the attribute name.

for example: Country flag instead of the text "country of manufacture", so also for other attributes

Which file should I modify to make it happen?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could modify `catalog/product/view/attributes.phtml`

```
<?php
    $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
    $_product = $this->getProduct()
?>
<?php if($_additional = $this->getAdditionalData()): ?>
    <h2><?php echo $this->__('Additional Information') ?></h2>
    <table class="data-table" id="product-attribute-specs-table">
        <col width="25%" />
        <col />
        <tbody>
        <?php foreach ($_additional as $_data): ?>
            <tr>
                <th class="label"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->__($_data['label'])) ?></th>
                <td class="data">
                    <?php /* Change here: */ ?>
                    <?php if ($_data['code'] == 'manufacturer'): ?>
                        Whatever you want.
                    <?php else: ?>
                        <?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code']) ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                 </td>
            </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <script type="text/javascript">decorateTable('product-attribute-specs-table')</script>
<?php endif;?>
```

**UPDATE**: answering your comment

You can filter attributes by loading them first and then get what fields you want. In the file above, you can use this piece of code:

```
$attribute = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')->getAttribute(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY, $_data['code']);

if ($attribute->getIsVisibleOnFront()) {
    // add a wrapper to display the icon, maybe?
}
```

I'd use "manual" `if`s (as I suggested in the first place) for this task because it's much faster.

Comment: hi Predram, this way I add my custom attributes, but if I wanted to add an icon for each attribute that I make visible in the frontend, without having to recall them one by one, how could I do?

Comment: Please see my update on the answer

Comment: Hi, well, I take the test and then I'll let you know the result...